# Creating TableLayout From Class

Tags: android, tablelayout

Icreate this post, because i am new at this, and i need a little help. I am doing a little exercise about a application you that with some values you can make a tablelayout from class. But after i push the button i get the error "The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first"

```
public class TabelFlat extends Activity{
    //deklarasi variabel
    String jumlah,jasa,jangkawaktu;
    int jum = 0, jsa = 0, jkwaktu = 0;
    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, d = 0, i = 0;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

        //mengambil value yg diimport dari class lain
        if (extras != null) {
            jumlah = extras.getString("jumlah");
            jasa = extras.getString("jasa");
            jangkawaktu = extras.getString("jangkawaktu");
    }
        //konversi string menjadi int
        jum = Integer.parseInt(jumlah);
        jsa = Integer.parseInt(jasa);
        jkwaktu = Integer.parseInt(jangkawaktu);

        //membuat tabel
        TableLayout MainLayout = new TableLayout(this);
        MainLayout.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
        MainLayout.setStretchAllColumns(true);

        //Baris Judul
        TableRow row1 = new TableRow(this);
        TextView text1 = new TextView(this);
        text1.setText("Bulan");
        TextView text2 = new TextView(this);
        text2.setText("Total Angsuran");
        TextView text3 = new TextView(this);
        text2.setText("Angsuran");
        TextView text4 = new TextView(this);
        text2.setText("Bunga");
        TextView text5 = new TextView(this);
        text2.setText("Sisa Saldo");
        text2.setGravity(android.view.Gravity.RIGHT);
        //memasukkan nilai text ke row
        row1.addView(text1);
        row1.addView(text2);
        row1.addView(text3);
        row1.addView(text4);
        row1.addView(text5);
        //menambah row ke tabel
        MainLayout.addView(row1);
        //kalkulasi
        TextView tangsuran = new TextView(this);
        a = (jum * 120/100);
        tangsuran.setText(""+String.valueOf(a));

        TextView angsuran = new TextView(this);
        b = jum / jkwaktu;
        angsuran.setText(""+String.valueOf(b));

        TextView bunga = new TextView(this);
        c = jum * 20 / 100 / jkwaktu;
        bunga.setText(""+String.valueOf(c));
        //loop

        d = jum;
        for (i = 1;i<=jkwaktu;i++){

            TableRow barisloop = new TableRow(this);
            //membuat string kosong untuk setiap kolom 
            TextView bulan = new TextView(this);
            bulan.setText(""+i);
            TextView sisa = new TextView(this);
            d = d - b;
            sisa.setText(""+String.valueOf(d));

            barisloop.addView(bulan);
            barisloop.addView(tangsuran);
            barisloop.addView(angsuran);
            barisloop.addView(bunga);
            barisloop.addView(sisa);

            MainLayout.addView(barisloop);
        }

        setContentView(MainLayout);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here you add the `tangsuran`, `angsuran` and `bunga` text view to new row, but they are already added to another one.You must create new objects for the rows in the loop.

```
for (i = 1;i<=jkwaktu;i++){

        TableRow barisloop = new TableRow(this);
        //membuat string kosong untuk setiap kolom 
        TextView bulan = new TextView(this);
        bulan.setText(""+i);
        TextView sisa = new TextView(this);
        d = d - b;
        sisa.setText(""+String.valueOf(d));

        barisloop.addView(bulan);
        //barisloop.addView(tangsuran);
        //barisloop.addView(angsuran);  CREATE NEW TEXTVIEWS
        //barisloop.addView(bunga);
        barisloop.addView(sisa);

        MainLayout.addView(barisloop);
    }
```